# Python Pandas Datetime loop by day

Tags: python, pandas

a simple example of what my pd looks like is :

```
DateTime               C_CL       C_EB
2018-01-03 10:30    -0.002726   -0.002921
2018-01-03 10:50    -0.005832   -0.005343
2018-01-03 11:10    -0.006966   -0.007278
2018-01-03 11:30    -0.01883    -0.019026
2018-01-04 10:30    -0.0021     -0.001261
2018-01-04 10:50     0.006887    0.00595
2018-01-04 11:10    -0.00076    -0.000717
2018-01-04 11:30     0.002282    0.002152
```

datetime is `dtype='datetime64[ns]'` so it is pretty easy to do something like `df['2018-01-04']` and it will pull up just that.

the question is how can I create an loop that would allow me to iterate over each day at a time with out knowing which days are in the time series.  I am not worried about time, simply just the day.  The reason for this is to do some calculations for that day only, append to the table and move to the next day.

Comment: Can you give an example of the types of calculations you want to do? It could be as simple as `groupby(df.DateTime.dt.day)`

Comment: @ALollz In this case I think it is the index so simply `df.groupby(df.index.day)`

Comment: @ALollz thank you for that clue.  i was actually able to do it using that and google to find the solution for `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')) `. then throwing that into a loop.

Comment: @blonc And what do you mean by a loop, what is your next step? To make efficient scripts you should avoid loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this helpful?

Recreate dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = '''\
DateTime               C_CL       C_EB
2018-01-03T10:30    -0.002726   -0.002921
2018-01-03T10:50    -0.005832   -0.005343
2018-01-03T11:10    -0.006966   -0.007278
2018-01-03T11:30    -0.01883    -0.019026
2018-01-04T10:30    -0.0021     -0.001261
2018-01-04T10:50     0.006887    0.00595
2018-01-04T11:10    -0.00076    -0.000717
2018-01-04T11:30     0.002282    0.002152'''

file = pd.compat.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\s+', parse_dates=['DateTime'], index_col=['DateTime'])
```

And here are a few operations you could run:

```
#df.groupby(df.index.date).sum()
#df.groupby(df.index.date).mean()
#df.groupby(df.index.date).std()
#df['sum_CL'] = df.groupby(df.index.date)['C_CL'].transform('sum')
#df.groupby(df.index.date)['C_CL'].agg(['sum','mean','std'])
```

Comment: this works perfect.  in trying to keep with not using loops why would something like the following not work? `df['C_CL'].groupby(df.index.date).corr(df['C_EB'].groupby(df.index.date))` . if do it with just `df.groupby()` it returns a matrix, so I was trying to do the `corr()` only with needed items

Comment: @blonc sec... it works ofc... but what is you want to do? Maybe: `df.groupby(df.index.date)[['C_CL','C_EB']].corr()`?